# Signal Strength on android saved as a variable

Tags: android, signal-strength

I'm trying to creat an app that would save the current signal strength. So far I've seen many examples that are all extending PhoneStateListener, but all of them use a Toast to display this information, like in this example:

http://www.firstdroid.com/2010/05/12/get-provider-gsm-signal-strength/

I was wondering a couple of things:

a) Do I always have to use the PhoneStateListener AND override the onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength) ?

b) How can I access the value signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength() from outside the PhoneStateListener class?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

U can try with it. I cant say its the final solution.If u want to access certain data from other activity, then try it with shared preference.Shared preference value is visible from other activities

Answer (score 0):

I might be late to answer your question, but if you are still looking for the answer, here it is:

a) yes you have to use the PhoneStateListener and override the onSignalStrengthsChanged as, in my knowledge that is the only way to get current cells' signal strength for GSM. The listener is only called in big signal strength changes, so you yourself cannot control the listener. the listener will automatically update or make a toast when it is called. So, it is better to declare the listener and ask it to listen at onCreate().

b) For accessing the the RSSI value from outside the Listener is not really difficult, just store the value in a variable and make a method like getRSSI(), which will return you the value when its called. The example is given below:

```
    public class GsmRSSI extends Activity{
    MyPhoneStateListener MyListener;
    TelephonyManager Tel;
    ArrayList<String> signalStrength = new ArrayList<String>();

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    MyListener = new MyPhoneStateListener();
    Tel = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    Tel.listen(MyListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);

    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            String rssi = MyListener.getStrength();
                            if(!rssi.equals(""))
                               signalStrength.add(rssi);
        }
    }, 0, 5000);//it will add the rssi value after every 5000ms
    }


       private class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    String gsmStrength = "";

    @Override
    public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength) {
        super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);
        gsmStrength = String.valueOf(signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength()* 2 - 113);           
    }

    public String getStrength() {
        return gsmStrength;
    }

    }
    }
```

This should do the work for you. But at the begining you might not get any rssi value for a little while as the listener is only called when there is a significant change in the rssi.